# Deleting Facebook comments on my website

Tags: facebook, comments

I have allowed user comments on my website with "facebook comment" and using the meta tag fb:admins I can hide comments. But this only hides them from people that are not friends with the person who left the comment. I need to be able to delete the comment. Sometimes I don't want friends of the commenter to be able to read it.

There is an option to use meta tag fb:app_id but this needs a facebook app. So I spent 8 hours creating an app as I thought that might do the trick. Before I got a chance to test it I had to upload screenshots and banners and all the rest. And finally Facebook say they will review it. To be honest I have no idea what app I have created as I thought having an empty app might force the delete button to come up when I use fb:app_id.

Googling around here I now see someone said "It's not a real app, it's just what facebook calls it. But how to I create this "false" app and will it do the trick?

Surely I can remove comments on my website if I don't like them? Or?

So, how do I delete comments from the ones people leave on my website? - There must be thousands of people looking for this option. Can't believe it isn't easier!

Comment: Facebook comments are currently unable to be deleted. However, if you use an app-id (as you have attempted) and associate that app-id to the site, you will be able to moderate comments from within the developer console - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments. On that link, you can access the Settings link and modify your app's settings such that all comments need to be moderated before they are visible. That way, you can approve only those comments that you deem fit. Agree it's not an optimal solution.